# create and insert in a single query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, create-table

```
    <?php     
mysql_query("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test.$p (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `title` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `colum` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `ord` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `tex` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `search` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `count` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      `order` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    )ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1 AUTO_INCREMENT=1; 
     INSERT INTO $p ( `title`, `colum`, `ord`, `tex`, `search`, `count`, `order`) VALUES
    ('$a',  '$b',  '$c',  '$d',  '$f',  '$h',  '$g'); ");
        ?>
```

I am working in a PHP language . $r is my database and $p is my table name
In this I am creating a table , if table is not created and if the table is created then i want to insert the values in the respective column given above  but I am not good at mysql_query so I don't know where to add the insert query

I found a solution for my problem but this code is properly working in the phpmyadmin but when i run this code using php , it show me nothing inthe database

Comment: To which programming language does `mysql_query` belong? PHP?

Comment: Pretty sure that they have to be two distinct calls.  Side note, why are you creating tables on the fly?

Comment: Hello and welcome to stackoverflow. Perhaps you should take some time to review your question in order to explain more clearly your problem and how you have tried to solve it until now. Once done, while waiting for answers you could take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers to know what you should do when someone answer to your question

Answer (score 1):

You can not execute two queries with a single `mysql_query()`.

Make another call to `mysql_query()` with the `INSERT` query as the parameter.

If you absolutely must execute multiple queries in a single function call, change your mysql engne to mysqli, then use `mysqli_multi_query()` like so:

```
mysqli_multi_query ($link, 'query1;query2;query3;...');
```

Please keep in mind that although both approaches issue queries sequentially, their execution is not atomic. If you need atomicity, use a `TRANSACTION`.

Comment: That won't work; you can only do a single query with `mysql_query`. To do what you suggest, you need to use mysqli's `mysqli_multi_query()` http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.multi-query.php

Comment: I am working on something in which if the table is created then insert the values and if the table is not created the ......**1st create it and then insert it** i have completed the 1st part and i am working on the bold part

Answer (score 0):

The [13.1.17. CREATE TABLE Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html) can do something like:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `table1` (
    `col1` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL,
    `col2` INT (11) DEFAULT NULL
)
SELECT 1 `col1`, 2 `col2`;
```

and should work with `mysql_query`

Comment: I don't want to select the values , i want to insert the values

Comment: With this insert the values ​​directly, here the example [SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/20c46/1)